# KendoDateTime picker- format

Tags: kendo-ui, knockout-kendo, kendo-datetimepicker

I have a knockout observable which holds the date and time. That observable is bound to kendoDateTime picker. I am not able to bind the observable value in the picker.
Here is the jsfiddle link for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/ye865/74/

JS Code:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.bigday = ko.observable("1997-07-16T19:20:30"); 
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

HTML code:

```
<span data-bind="text: bigday"></span>
<input data-bind="kendoDateTimePicker: { value: bigday, format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm' }" />
```

The observable value: **"1997-07-16T19:20:30"** should be bound to the dateTimePicker.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How would i format the date which is stored in the observable? suppose i want to store the datetime in the observable with format= yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm . How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is incorrect: you are missing the `T` and the hours should be `HH`:

```
format: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'
```

But you probably want to put this in the `parseFormats` options so the display doesn't have the T:

```
<input id="text" data-bind="kendoDateTimePicker: { value: bigday, 
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', parseFormats: ['yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm']}" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FXht/).

To have a selected date in a formatted way in an observable you need to have a separate observable, because the `value` property of the date picker returns a `Date` object you need to format it manually as a string, for example using a `computed`:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.bigday = ko.observable("1997-07-16T19:20:30");
    self.formatted = ko.computed(function() {
        return kendo.toString(self.bigday(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    });
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5yug/).

You can even feed back the formatted value to your original `bigday`:

```
self.bigday = ko.observable("1997-07-16T19:20:30");
self.bigday.subscribe(function() {
    self.bigday(kendo.toString(self.bigday(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'));
});
```

Demo [JSFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RL2Z5/).